# Change background with jQuery addClass

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the background color by adding a new class with another background color. But the color don't change. It's still the same color! Do I have to remove the old background color first? I guess my code should work!?

```
$(".displayControl a:first").addClass("activeButton");
```

The css

```
.displayControl
{
padding: 20px 0 0 0;
float: right;
}

.displayControl a
{
background: #B7BABD;
margin: 0 5px 0 0;
padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
color: #ffffff;
}

.activeButton
{
background: #83AEE6;
}
```

Comment: Post associated markup or a jsfiddle link, so we can understand your question better.

Comment: jsfiddle please.. Need to see that the selector is working..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are being defeated by CSS's "specificity" rules. The more specific directive is winning the day despite being higher in the style sheet.

Try changing the last directive to :

```
.displayControl a.activeButton
{
background: #83AEE6;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your .activeButton css declaration is not specific enough, the ".displayControl a" selector is more specific so the background from that declaration is used (it has priority over the less specific .activeButton declaration). You should make your activeButton selector more specific, like this:

```
.displayControl a.activeButton{
    background: #83AEE6;
}  ​
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5RaH/)

Answer (score 1):

`.displayControl a` has more priority than `.activeButton`

Try this instead,

```
.displayControl
{
padding: 20px 0 0 0;
float: right;
}

.displayControl a
{
background: #B7BABD;
margin: 0 5px 0 0;
padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
color: #ffffff;
}

.displayControl .activeButton
{
background: #83AEE6;
}​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cVpUA/)

Answer (score 0):

kreativ,

Would you please try this:

```
    <div class='asd'>
    Something
    </div>

    .asd{background:#B7BABD;}
    .new{background:red;}

   $('div.asd').addClass(function(){
   $(this).css('background','');
   $(this).addClass('new');       
   });
```

See it in http://jsfiddle.net/QV2m3/

thanks